# Самописная анимация вращение + масштабирование

Tags: actionscript-3, анимация, flash

Схожу сума, не знаю что делать. Не понимаю по чему, но на мой вопрос не ответил не один человек с форумов на которых я задавал его. Дело вот в чем - хочу и нужно сделать анимацию вращения и масштабирования при помощи тригонометрии. С начала я делал по отдельности, вращение, масштабирование, и всё получалось на отлично. Но был один нюанс из - за которого я пересмотрел выбранный подход и перенёс все расчёты в один метод. Но проблема не исчезла.
С точки зрения вычислений всё верно, я проверял на листочке и в программах по вычислению математики. А сама проблема вот в чём - если делать увеличение при вращении, то всё хорошо, но если уменьшение, при чем уменьшение с 1 до 0.5 всё сбивается. Я надеюсь, что хоть тут найдётся человек, который сможет помочь. Вот сам код :

```
package
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class MatrixTest0 extends Sprite 
    {
        private var sprite:Sprite;
        private static var DEG_TO_RAD:Number = 3.1415926535897932 / 180;
        private var center:Point;
        private var allTime:Number = 0;
        private var duration:Number = 5;

        public function MatrixTest0() 
        {
            center = new Point(250, 250);
            sprite = new Sprite();
            sprite.graphics.beginFill(0x8E6828);
            sprite.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
            sprite.graphics.endFill();
            sprite.x = sprite.y = 200;
            addChild(sprite);

            var r:Number = Math.sqrt((sprite.x - center.x) * (sprite.x - center.x) + (sprite.y - center.y) * (sprite.y - center.y));

            var circle:Sprite = new Sprite();
            circle.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xffffff);
            circle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, r);
            circle.graphics.endFill();
            circle.x = circle.y = 250;
            addChild(circle);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
        }
        private function scaleRotationPoint(target:DisplayObject, point:Point, scaleX:Number, scaleY:Number, angle:Number=NaN):void
        {
            var a0:Number = -target.rotation;
            var c0:Number = Math.cos(a0 * DEG_TO_RAD);
            var s0:Number = Math.sin(a0 * DEG_TO_RAD);
            var dX0:Number = target.x - point.x
            var dY0:Number = target.y - point.y

            target.rotation = 0;
            target.x = Math.round(point.x + dX0 * c0 - dY0 * s0);
            target.y = Math.round(point.y + dY0 * c0 + dX0 * s0);
            //возвращаю стартовые кординаты вектора, который соответствует
            //косинусу и синусу без масштабирования
            var sXS:Number = Math.round((target.x - point.x) / target.scaleX)
            var sYS:Number = Math.round((target.y - point.y) / target.scaleY)
            //нахожу вектор ( косинус, синус ) который будет после масштабирования
            var sXF:Number = sXS * scaleX;
            var sYF:Number = sYS * scaleY;

            var cos:Number = Math.cos(angle * DEG_TO_RAD);
            var sin:Number = Math.sin(angle * DEG_TO_RAD);
            //это конечные координаты с учетом поворота
            var nX:Number = point.x + sXF * cos - sYF * sin;
            var nY:Number = point.y + sXF * cos + sXF * sin;

            target.rotation = angle;
            target.scaleX=scaleX
            target.scaleY = scaleY
            target.x = nX
            target.y = nY
        }
        private function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void 
        {
            var time:Number = 1 / 1000 * stage.frameRate;
            allTime += time;
            var ratio:Number = allTime / duration;
            if (allTime>=duration) ratio=1;

            this.scaleRotationPoint(sprite, center,ratio*0.5+1,ratio*0.5+1,ratio*360);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Варианты:

1) Перед трансформацией объекта переместите его центр в середину, относительно родителя, при необходимости вплоть до добавления "искусственного" пустого родителя.

```
var B:Sprite = new Sprite();
B.addChild(A); // A - целевой объект
A.x = -A.width/2;
A.y = -A.height/2;
```

2) Задание центра трансформаций через матрицу объекта.

```
public function setRegistrationPoint(s:Sprite, regx:Number, regy:Number, showRegistration:Boolean )
{
    s.transform.matrix = new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -regx, -regy);
}
```

Comment: @ShockWave: Спасибо Вам! Такой ответ я получаю каждый раз, как задаю этот вопрос. Первый вариант я не рассматриваю вообще, так как только учусь и хочу научится делать при помощи тригонометрии. А вот почему все рекомендуют матрицы мне не понятно, они же на тридцать процентов медленнее работают чем тоже самое созданное при помощи Math.. Буду тогда сам искать причину, хотя уже надежды нет.